# How to save google Timeline chart

Tags: java, charts, google-visualization

I have created linecharts & timeline charts using google-chart api.
I need to save them in .jpg format. 
I am able to save linecharts using chart.getImageURI() & Base64.decodeBase64 functions .
But I am unable to save timeline chart as getImageURI() function is not defined for timeline charts .

I have even tried using BufferedImage & ImageIO.read as follows :

```
BufferedImage timeLineImage;
URL url = new URL(TimeLineURL);
timeLineImage = ImageIO.read(url);
ImageIO.write(timeLineImage, "jpg",new File("C:\\out.jpg"))
```

But I am getting Exception saying timeLineImage  is null.

Any help to save timeline charts would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a site where there are samples which use Google charts for most all chart types and an external server to render to PDF and image types. You can control the image format and DPI if you like.

The one key thing is that the Google api does not add the SVG namespace into a generated SVG so there is a callback created that adds this namespace. You have to do this or the remote formatting service will not process the SVG.

http://www.cloudformatter.com/GoogleCharts

Line Chart: http://www.cloudformatter.com/GoogleCharts.GoogleChartSamples.GoogleLineCharts
or on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/22bep76q/

Timeline Chart:
http://www.cloudformatter.com/GoogleCharts.GoogleChartSamples.GoogleTimelineCharts
or on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q2h8quho/

Sample code for Timeline:

```
<!-- This adds the proper namespace on the generated SVG -->
function AddNamespace(){
var svg = jQuery('#chart_div svg');
svg.attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
svg.css('overflow','visible');
}
<!-- This generates the google chart -->
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
             function drawChart() {
             var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
             var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
             var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

             dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
             dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
             dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
             dataTable.addRows([
             [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
             [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
             [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ],
             [ 'Madison', new Date(1809, 2, 4), new Date(1817, 2, 4) ],
             [ 'Monroe',      new Date(1817, 2, 4),  new Date(1825, 2, 4) ],
             [ 'Quincy Adams', new Date(1825, 3, 30), new Date(1829, 2, 4) ],
             [ 'Jackson',      new Date(1829, 2, 4),  new Date(1837, 2, 4) ],
             [ 'Van Buren', new Date(1837, 2, 4), new Date(1841, 2, 4) ],
             [ 'Harrison',      new Date(1841, 2, 4),  new Date(1841, 3, 4) ],
             [ 'Tyler', new Date(1841, 3, 4), new Date(1845, 2, 4) ]]);

             google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', AddNamespace);
             chart.draw(dataTable);
             }
 <!-- @cloudformatter calls to render the SVG -->

 <!-- Convert the SVG to PDF and download it -->
 var click="return xepOnline.Formatter.Format('JSFiddle', {render:'download', srctype:'svg'})";
 jQuery('#buttons').append('<button onclick="'+ click +'">PDF</button>');
 <!-- Convert the SVG to PNG@120dpi and open it -->
 click="return xepOnline.Formatter.Format('JSFiddle', {render:'newwin', mimeType:'image/png', resolution:'120', srctype:'svg'})";
 jQuery('#buttons').append('<button onclick="'+ click +'">PNG @120dpi</button>');
 <!-- Convert the SVG to JPG@300dpi and open it -->
 click="return xepOnline.Formatter.Format('JSFiddle', {render:'newwin', mimeType:'image/jpg', resolution:'300', srctype:'svg'})";
 jQuery('#buttons').append('<button onclick="'+ click +'">JPG @300dpi</button>');
```